# Default CSS overriding media query

Tags: css, media-queries

I'm getting this from Chrome ADB plugin, connecting to my phone via USB. Basically allowing me to inspect elements on my android chrome and view or alter them on my connected PC.

I am getting this strange issue. I thought media queries were to overrule generic class rules, but if you see this image you can see that the media query rules are being overridden. I COULD fix this by adding `!important` but I would rather not, I also realize that the rule for non-media-queried container h1 is declared AFTER the media query rule. I am not sure if that is why, or if there is another reason. Can anyone explain why this is happening?

[image]

CSS code:

```
@media screen and (max-device-width: 767px) {
  .container > h1 {
    font-size: 40px;
    line-height: 40px; }
    ...some more rules... }
.container > h1 {
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 80px;
    font-weight: 300;
    line-height: 80px; }
```

### EDIT - Added Example

See this: http://jsfiddle.net/djuKS/
*Notice if you swap the rule order, the behaviour is as expected. But by default the media query is being overridden*

Comment: Why do you think media queries take precedence? They do not. Later rules override them.

Comment: Because using a media query logically adds an additional level of specificity to any rule. Perhaps this is not the case as I am finding

Comment: They do not add specificity/priority in the sense of the cascade, as you have learned.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

> I thought media queries were to overrule generic class rules,

Rules inside a MQ are rules like any other one in terms of priority of their selector, except they will only apply depending on the conditions of the at-media.

> (...)  I also realize that the rule for non-media-queried
>   container h1 is declared AFTER the media query rule.

You found the correct reason: both rules have exactly the same priority (specificity) as they have the exact same selector. If a property is part of both rules (and the declaration is valid and both of them or none of them has `!important` modifier), then the value of the **last declaration written** will apply.
That's the reason you'll always find MQ written at the end (except rules applying to IE8- via conditional classes, no possible overlap between MQ and modern browsers and IE8- :) )

Comment: I thought about the specificity, but why wouldn't applying a media style add specificity? Its kind of weird, but I can live with it like this.

Comment: It only adds a condition to be applied, but yes it wouldn't be unexpected if the spec was different and it added some specificity. Though we already have 4 levels of specificity (element, classes, id and in style attribute plus star that gives no specificity but still applies) in 5 types of stylesheets (UA, user, author, author with `!important` and user with `!important`)...

Answer (score 0):

Great point raised in FelipeAls's answer.

To get around this limitation, I used a media query nested inside my rule, like so:

Current way:

```
@media screen and (max-device-width: 767px) {
    selector {
        rule: "desired value";
    }
}

...

selector {
    rule: "default value";
}
```

The way I did it:

```
selector {
    rule: "default value";
    @media screen and (max-device-width: 767px) {
        rule: "desired value";
    }
}
```

This way, the desired value always comes after the default one. Note that with this you'll have to write mutually exclusive media queries or you might find you have the wrong value applied just because it comes later on in your stylesheet. The answer to *that* - well - is just to write more specific selectors :)