# Website uses original CSS code over @media device when minimised

Tags: html, css

I am trying to get my website to be media responsive.

In standard mode this is the css code for a div:

```
      position: relative;
      z-index: 10;
      top: 190px;
      background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
      padding: 22px 10px 10px 10px;
      margin: 0 auto;
      max-width: 700px;
```

Then when it goes to a small device, this is how the CSS should be:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 740px){
#outside-main-search {
      position: absolute;
      margin-top: 0;
      top: 100%;         
      }
}
```

The problem the `@media` is not overwriting the existing code so if I use dev tools this is how it's showing:

[image]

Above are the results of when the page is minimised, why is it no overriding the css code above?

Comment: If not wrong than you also missing closing bracket in media query

Comment: it does work - check this http://jsfiddle.net/Nave4/ for reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your CSS,
is your

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 740px)
```

**AFTER** the first

```
#outside-main-search
```

?

Because if not, then *#outside-main-search* will apply over the *@media only screen and (max-width: 740px)*

(CSS is cascading style sheet, so the last one that applies is the used one)

Your chrome show that the media specific is applied BEFORE the not specific.

Comment: yes, the first `#outside...` is after `@media`, do I need to add it before? I will try this now

Comment: turns out I did make the mistake you mentioned above. Thanks stadja!

Answer (score 0):

In your HTML, add this inside your `head` area:

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`

And in your CSS, add this:

```
@viewport {
    width: device-width;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the CSS file, place

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 740px){
    #outside-main-search {
        position: absolute;
        margin-top: 0;
        top: 100%;         
    }
}
```

at the very bottom of the CSS file and make sure there is no code below the file. Does this work?

Rules inside a MQ are rules like any other one in terms of priority of their selector, except they will only apply depending on the conditions of the at-media.

Rules have exactly the same priority (specificity) as they have the exact same selector. If a property is part of both rules (and the declaration is valid and both of them or none of them has !important modifier), then the value of the last declaration written will apply.

That's the reason you'll always find MQ written at the end (as stated here: [Default CSS overriding media query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18395316/default-css-overriding-media-query))