# Media queries only work with !important

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries

it turns out to try to change styles according your screen resolution using media queries do not work if I placed an! Important behind. I am filling the code Important to work and I do not understand is because they operate without the Important put here an example!:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {


.logo img{

    padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;

    }
}


.logo img{
    width:100%;
    max-width:60%;
    padding: 164px 0px 0px 0px;

    }
```

If you do not put the important behind not working. Maybe it's a silly question but brings me head the problem and can not find the solution.

Comment: Your media queries are probably [being overridden](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18395316/default-css-overriding-media-query) by a non-media query CSS rule.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you have to put the media queries AFTER the general CSS - the later rules will overwrite the ones that come before them, and if they are not in a media query, they are valid for everything...

Comment: But what the hell, you're right, do you want me to believe that nobody has explained it or I could find information on the Internet? Took hours brooding, THANK YOU !!